# Orion (IBM DevOps Services) : Is it possible to specify ecmaScript parser to 6 or 7?

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, eclipse-orion

In IBM DevOps Services, there is web editor (Orion base). Looks like the ecmaScript parser by ESLint is version 5 by default. Is it possible to use version 6 ? The following did not work.

```
/*eslint-env es6*/
```

I checked JavaScript configuration, but does not have it. The problem I have is WebIDE gives me errors on "class".

```
class Hoge {}
```

Shows error in the editor.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to specify ECMA 6, but it requires the use of a `.tern-project` configuration file at the root of your project.

For example:

```
MyProject
   .tern-project
```

Inside the file you, can specify a bunch of things (all of which are mentioned [here](http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#configuration)), but the ones to set the ECMA level are `ecmaVersion` and `libs`.

So to set ECMA 6, your `.tern-project` file would look something like:

```
{
    "libs": ["ecma5", "ecma6"],
    "ecmaVersion": 6
}
```

At the moment though, the Orion editor is not 100% ECMA 6 compliant, so even though you can turn on the features, they might not all work.

The work to complete ECMA 6 compliance is taking place in [Orion bug 460728](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=460728).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this option.